# Getting redirect link using HTTPClient post

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the redirect url using the headers, so I googled around and found a few examples:

```
Header[] arr = httpResponse.getHeaders("Location");
for (Header head : arr){
    String whatever = arr.getValue();
}
```

AND

```
HttpPost request1 = new HttpPost("https://hrlink.healthnet.com/");
HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(request1);

// expect a 302 response.
if (response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 302) {
  String redirectURL = response1.getFirstHeader("Location").getValue();

  // no auto-redirecting at client side, need manual send the request.
  HttpGet request2 = new HttpGet(redirectURL);
  HttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(request2);

  ... ...
}
```

Where they get "Location" from header, however I am not able to pull the "Location" out of the HttpResponseMessage from my version, I tried moving things here and there but it does not contain the method to accept the parameter, how am I able to get the redirect URL using httpClient?

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "---"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "---")
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

var response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;


HttpHeaders headerlist = response.Headers;

foreach (var header in headerlist)
{
    //Red line on header("Location")
    label1.Text += header("Location") + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Set AllowAutoRedirect to false : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect(v=vs.110).aspx then you can find "Location"

Comment: @x... how do I get "Location" from HttpWebResponse?

Comment: HttpWebResponse.Headers : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.headers(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for test, with www.google.com you can test redirection:

```
  var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
  request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
  using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
  {
    string location = response.Headers["Location"];
    Console.WriteLine(location);
  }
```